# Return Relative Cell Reference in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking up some things on the `Address` function, but whenever it is called on a specific range of cells I get the absolute cell reference value instead of the *relative* cell reference.

I'm wondering if there's a way to return it without the '$'. I'm used to the `ADDRESS` formula, but haven't used it's VBA equivalent before. Is there a way to give the function a reference type like you can with the formula?

Comment: You can just use the `Replace` function to replace all the `$` with an empty string...

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit foolish, but I suppose I just hadn't phrased my question well enough in previous attempts to find out.

It is done by using (0,0) as arguments. i.e. `myWorksheet.Cells(2,2).Address(0,0)` will return B2

Comment: you can edit your question instead of replying to it as an answer...

Comment: Oh true. I just used the "Answer Your Question" button, but that also works.

Comment: Actually, you've answered your own question, which is perfectly acceptable, and I'd argue preferred to editing the original. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @SiddharthRout I should have looked for the actual documentation, yes. I did Google it, however whatever I original searched for didn't come up with what I needed. If you read the "I just hadn't phrased my question well enough in previous attempts to find out." portion of my answer, you'd know that I actually made an attempt :)

Comment: `.address vba` If you search this in google, see what do you get :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Like I said, I hadn't phrased it well enough. I suppose being more concise and direct typically yields better results, in this case, actual documentation. I'll take your comment as a lesson then.